# Setting a pointer to NULL in C, not compiling

Tags: c, pointers, null

for some reason, when I try to compile my code the .exe file just disappears after its done... without any errors or warnings.

This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student_ 
{
    int matnum;
    char vorname[20];
    struct student_ *next;
} student;

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    student hans;
    hans.matnum = 12;

    student peter;
    peter.matnum = 13;
    peter.next = NULL; // THIS PART CAUSES MY PROBLEM

    hans.next = &peter;

    student *curr = &hans;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("matnum: %d\n", (*curr).matnum);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

What I want it to do is iterate through curr and set it to the next everytime curr wasn't NULL already. So if next is NULL, than the while-loop should stop.

```
peter.next = NULL; // THIS PART CAUSES MY PROBLEM
```

This is how I want to achieve that but it doesn't work. :\

---

From the comments:

> I don't get an error. AFter I type in "gcc -Wall -o test test.c" the test.exe is there for a second and then it gets deleted.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; either it compiles, or it doesn't and you get error messages.

Comment: Is it compilation error, or run time error? Can you please copy the error text and paste in your question?

Comment: I don't get an error. AFter I type in "gcc -Wall -o test test.c" the test.exe is there for a second and then it gets deleted.

Comment: Does it remain when you delete the suspect line of code?

Comment: Yes. But then the program crashes, which makes sense because the pointer curr is set to something that is not a student.

Answer (score 6):

The most plausible explanation for this is that your anti-virus software is deleting the executable. Your program compiles and runs fine here.

For whatever reason, the suspect line results in compiled code that your anti-virus software matches against a known virus. When you remove that line, it no longer matches the virus, but of course the program fails.

Temporarily disable your anti-virus to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: Holy cow I turned avast off and it works now! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @David +1 it was out of the box